# Trouble displaying multidimensional array in a div

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, sorting

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyRI0.png)
I am wanting the numbers to appear like a matrix when the button is clicked, I don't know how to use a multidimensional array to get the expected output(Click the blue link). Any help ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="rightDiv">
<div id = "pastcalcblock"> 
    <h3> PAST CALCULATIONS </h3>
         <input type = "text" size = "1" id = "text1"/>
         <input type = "text" size = "1" id = "text2"/>
         <input type = "text" size = "1" id = "text3"/>
         <input type = "text" size = "1" id = "text4"/><br>
         <input type = "button" value = "Ok" id = "operation" onClick = "display()"/>
         <div id = "resultTab">
                SORT<br>
                    <input type = "button" value = "As Entered" id = "enteredBut">
                    <input type = "button" value = "By Result" id = "resultBut"><br><br>
                    <div id = "expressions"></hr></div>                 
            </div>
        </div>

<script>
function display()
{
    var arrayOne =  [document.getElementById('text1').value,document.getElementById('text2').value,document.getElementById('text3').value,document.getElementById('text4').value ][];


    document.getElementById("expressions").innerHTML = arrayOne;
    var para = document.createElement("P");
    var t = document.createTextNode("arrayOne");
    para.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("expresions").appendChild(para);
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only correct the `arrayOne` without []

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1g6bsfny/)

Comment: I want the arrays to appear like a matrix. How can I do that ?

Comment: A ok matrix as your image, is equals as your example, only there is a mistake in "expresions" is "expressions" here with the correct example [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1g6bsfny/3/)

Comment: 1 2 3 4                                                                                                         1 1 1 1

Comment: not, watch the last updated fiddle is as a matriz, [JsFiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/1g6bsfny/3/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I didn't see the file earlier.